# Basic Kotlin methods missing in Kotlin Multiplatform

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-multiplatform

I just started working on a Kotlin Multiplatform project with jetpack compose and I love it. But I dont understand, why I get the following errors:

1. I cant use stuff like System.setProperty(), System is highlighted red and I cant import it. See https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/java/lang/System
2. I always get a "Kotlin not configured" warning in Android Studio, tried validating cache, restarting IDE and so on.

This is my build.gradle.kts:

```
import org.jetbrains.compose.desktop.application.dsl.TargetFormat
import org.jetbrains.compose.ExperimentalComposeLibrary

val ksoupVersion = "0.0.2"
val precomposeVersion = "1.5.7"
val htmlUnitVersion = "3.7.0"
val seleniumVersion = "4.15.0"

plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinMultiplatform)
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrainsCompose)
}

kotlin {
    androidTarget {
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions {
                jvmTarget = "1.8"
            }
        }
    }
    
    jvm("desktop")
    
    listOf(
        iosX64(),
        iosArm64(),
        iosSimulatorArm64()
    ).forEach { iosTarget ->
        iosTarget.binaries.framework {
            baseName = "ComposeApp"
            isStatic = true
        }
    }
    
    sourceSets {
        val desktopMain by getting
        
        androidMain.dependencies {
            implementation(libs.compose.ui)
            implementation(libs.compose.ui.tooling.preview)
            implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
        }
        desktopMain.dependencies {
            implementation(compose.desktop.currentOs)
        }
        commonMain.dependencies {
            implementation(projects.shared)
            implementation(compose.runtime)
            implementation(compose.foundation)
            implementation(compose.material3)
            @OptIn(ExperimentalComposeLibrary::class)
            implementation(compose.components.resources)
            implementation(compose.materialIconsExtended)

            // HIER DEPENDENCIES HINZUFÜGEN
            // KSOUP
            implementation("com.fleeksoft.ksoup:ksoup:$ksoupVersion")

            // PRECOMPOSE NAVIGATION
            implementation("moe.tlaster:precompose:$precomposeVersion")

            // HTMLUNIT / SELENIUM
            //runtimeOnly(group = "org.htmlunit", name = "htmlunit3-android", version = "3.7.0")
            //runtimeOnly(group= "org.seleniumhq.selenium", name = "selenium-java", version =  "3.+" )
            implementation("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:$seleniumVersion")
        }
    }
}

android {
    namespace = "org.example.project"
    compileSdk = libs.versions.android.compileSdk.get().toInt()

    sourceSets["main"].manifest.srcFile("src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml")
    sourceSets["main"].res.srcDirs("src/androidMain/res")
    sourceSets["main"].resources.srcDirs("src/commonMain/resources")

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "org.example.project"
        minSdk = libs.versions.android.minSdk.get().toInt()
        targetSdk = libs.versions.android.targetSdk.get().toInt()
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = libs.versions.compose.compiler.get()
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    dependencies {
        debugImplementation(libs.compose.ui.tooling)
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
    // ODER DOCH HIER?
}

compose.desktop {
    application {
        mainClass = "MainKt"

        nativeDistributions {
            targetFormats(TargetFormat.Dmg, TargetFormat.Msi, TargetFormat.Deb)
            packageName = "org.example.project"
            packageVersion = "1.0.0"
        }
    }
}
```

What do I have to add here to get those basic kotlin things working?

Comment: check out [Why isn't it good to ask multiple questions and answers in one question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371614/why-isnt-it-good-to-ask-multiple-questions-and-answers-in-one-question#:~:text=Each%20question%20on%20Stack%20Overflow,ever%20find%20that%20information%20again.). Your first question is quite trivial - you can't use any java sourced code in `commonMain`, System is from `java.lang` so it's obviously not available, you need to find a kotlin analog of the function you'd like to use, or create expect/actual function and return value on each platform individually

Comment: @PhilDukhov thank you, I just started out with kmp so I didnt know that. Gonna read into expect/actual.

Comment: About the second question - there can be many reason - in my case helped to update do AS Hedgehog (now in RC3) - https://developer.android.com/studio/preview